# How to set the primary key of type hash using JPA?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, primary-key

When specifying a field as primary key with `@Id`, the result is a `BTREE` index, at least when using MySQL. How can I set it to be a HASH index?

Comment: You can't because hibernate does not choose the index but MySQL does automatically. You should consider using SQL to create the database tables.

Comment: Which JPA implementation? WIth Hibernate (via a custom dialect) I cannot see any way to add the necessary clause. Other JPA providers may be more extensible when it comes to DDL.